# bookdown gitbook format: Different text for text header and ToC at the sidebar?

Tags: r, bookdown, gitbook

Using bookdown with the Gitbook format: The text of my headers is sometimes too long to display completely in the TOC sidebar.

Is there a way to provide different text for the text header and for the menu at the sidebar? For instance: "This is a long header displayed in my text" which is abbreviated in the TOC sidebar with "Long Text Header".